# How to get Jenkins build history in a Groovy script? Which information are available for every build?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl, hudson-plugins

I have a groovy script that runs as a shared library and get jenkins build details.

```
projects = Jenkins.instance.getJob('ABB').getItems()

for( build in projects.getAllJobs())
{
 //process build data
  build.getDuration();
  build.getTime();
  etc.

}
```

Can some one tell me how I can see all the get methods (all metadata related to build) that I can access by using the **build** variable? Is there any Javadoc for this? I am not able to find? As of now it access Duration and Time but I want to know what all info can I get.

Comment: I was asked at work how to do it, so I prepared a script: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67370232/4944847. I didn't extend my answer in this thread, because here the main question was how to get available methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Jenkins provides Javadoc: https://javadoc.jenkins.io/

`build` is an instance of the [hudson.model.Run](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Run.html) interface.

Of course the instance may provide more details because every type of job (FreeStyle, Pipeline etc.) may return an object with more details. For example new pipelines use [org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-job/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/WorkflowRun.html).

The easiest option is to check the class and next search for its Javadoc :)

```
for (def build in projects.allJobs) {
    echo "${build.class}"
}
```

Comment: thanks.It helps. Can you tell me one thing. In the jenkins class, how can I seethe return type of "instance" variable ?I mean , "Jenkins.instance"?

Comment: `Jenkins.instance` in Groovy is the same as `Jenkins.getInstance()` in Java. So you are interested in this method declaration: [jenkins.model.Jenkins#getInstance](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html#getInstance--)

Comment: ok got it. I have not used groovy before. Is there a rule like Jenkins.instance is interprated as means Jenkins.getInstance() ? Becasue method calling is done like ClassName.Function as in code i shraed build.getTime() etc.,

Comment: Getters and setters in Groovy are described here: https://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_getters_and_setters. You may replace `obj.getTime()` by `obj.time`, `obj.isFoo()` by `obj.foo` and `obj.setBar(value)` by `obj.bar = value`.